# How to add label dynamically in iPad

Tags: ipad, xcode4.2

I have to build application in which I have to add labels dynamically so can you suggest the way please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)addLabelWithText: (NSString*)text toView: (UIView*)view withFrame: (CGRect)frame {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    [label setText: text];
    [view addSubview: label];
    [label release];
}
```

And somewhere else in you viewController:

```
[self addLabelWithText: @"Cool Label" toView: [self view] withFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
```